# Get textfield content

Tags: java, android, xml

I am new to android developing. In an XML file I have 2 numeric text fields and a button, by pressing the button I want to get the content of textfields that user entered and use it in another class, I know I should use `button.OnClickListener` method but what to put in this function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think if you break your problem step by step and Google that, you'll be able to get you answers. Its all a matter of putting things together.

Questions you can ask yourself:

1. How to get data from TextView?
2. How to send it to another activity?
3. how to receive the data in another activity?

For the sake of convenience, here is something that can help you:

Inside that function (`button.OnClickListener`) try to get the text from `TextView` like:

```
TextView tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
String input1 = tv1.getText().toString(); //tv1 is textView
TextView tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv2);
String input2 = tv2.getText().toString();
```

Then you can transfer that text to another activity using intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent(CurrentClassName.this, DestinationClass.class);
i.putExtra("text1", input1); //include the strings that you got from textView
i.putExtra("text2", input2);
startActivity(i);
```

Inside the destination activity you can extract these strings in `onCreate()` like:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String text1 = intent.getExtras().getString("text1");
String text2 = intent.getExtras().getString("text2");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: these are strings but I need int, what to do?

Comment: If you are sure your String contains an Integer, you can use: int myinteger = Integer.valueOf(input1);

Comment: @AmirSadegh If you are using a bundle instead of intent you can specify `int` or `String` by `Bundle.putInt()/Bundle.getInt()` and `Bundle.putString()/Bundle.getString()`

Comment: If you need Integer then ask yourself another question: "How to convert String to Integer"? and as @Phil has rightly suggested the answer, it would help you convert it. :) Suggestion from @ Thynk Apps is also something which you can consider including to your code. Just a suggestion going through some basic tutorial would be a good option before you ask. Just ask the right question to yourself and Google and you'll get all the right answers ;)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are setting `android:id` for the text fields in the layout file. Once you have done that from within `button.OnClickListener` you can get find the text view by id and get the text as follows:

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.id_of_text_field);
String text = tv.getText().toString();
```

Then to transfer to another activity add the string to a `Bundle` and add the `Bundle` to the `Intent` as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

bundle.putString(KEY_TO_FIND_STRING, text);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in your new activity you get the string from the bundle as follows:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
String text = null;

if( b != null ){
     text = b.getString(KEY_TO_FIND_STRING);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `SetOnClickListner` of `Button` takes an instance of `View.OnClickListener`, this instance is usually implemented anonymously like so:

```
button.setOnClickListner(new View.OnClickListner(){
   public void onClick(View v){
      //code which runs when action performed
   }
}
```

inside this listener you can implement your logic, for instance adding up the two numbers

```
String s1 = editText1.getText();
String s2 = editText2.getText();
int sum = Integer.parseInt(s1) + Integer.parseInt(s2);
```

You can look at `Shobhit Puri`'s for more details

see:

[listeneres](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/)

[View.OnClickListner](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener%28android.view.View.OnClickListener%29)